# Найти минимальное и максимальное число в строке

Tags: javascript, строки

Задача. Нужно найти максимальное и минимальное число в строке. Важно, именно в строке. Не переводя её в массив. Проблема: есть решение, но не могу понять, почему это решение работает. Может ли кто-то разжевать?

````
let str = '4 98 4 6 1 32 4 65 4 3 5 7 89 7 10 1 36 8 57';

let current = '',
    max = -Infinity,
    min = Infinity;

for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){
    if (str[i] !== ' '){
        current += str[i];
    }else{
        if (min > +current) min = +current;
        if (max < +current) max = +current;
        current = '';
    }
}
document.write(`Минимум ${min}. Максимум ${max}.`);```
````

Comment: _не могу понять, почему это решение работает_ - потому что оно не работает на самом деле. Не проверяется последнее число

Answer (score -1):

Интересный код, жаль что не рабочий

```
let str = '4 98 4 6 1 32 4 65 4 3 5 7 89 7 10 1 36 8 57';

let current = '',
    max = -Infinity, // нужен для первого цикла
    min = Infinity; // нужен для первого цикла 

for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){ // *1 
    if (str[i] !== ' '){ // если это символ то
        current += str[i]; // записываем его в виде строки '9' + '8' = '98'
    }else{
        if (min > +current) min = +current; // 4 > 98 стало +числом = false
        if (max < +current) max = +current; // 4 < 98 true max = 98
        current = ''; // current чист, начинаем сначала
    }
}
document.write(`Минимум ${min}. Максимум ${max}.`);
```

*1 str.length = кол-ву элементов в строке, length возвращает человеческий счёт, начиная с единицы, а не с 0, а в строке как и в массиве счёт идёт с нуля, выходит последний цикл вызовет несуществующий символ строки, получим str[i] = undefined. Ошибка будет заметна, если в строке последний элемент будет минимальным по значению, и скрипт его не вернёт в качестве минимального.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _length возвращает человеческий счёт, начиная с единицы, а не с 0_ - что-то странное написано

Comment: Как понятнее написать , что счёт при помощи метода length начинается с единицы (1), а не с нуля (0). Смотрите, строка "Я ничего не понимаю" имеет 19 индексов 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... 17, 18. Первый индекс нулевой (0), если мы возьмем последний индекс, 18 будет ли он равен количеству индексов? Ответ: нет. Т.к. их количество 19, можно посчитать с первого: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... , 18, 19.

Comment: @Евгений, при length счет никак не начинается, потому что это просто количество.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. По крайней мере стало гораздо понятнее, это правда помогло. Есть, конечно, нюансы, но я хоть могу двигаться дальше.